# data transfer among components using react

Tags: reactjs

I have a Landing.js

```
             protected getSelectedRow() {
              const rowUuids = this.getTable().getSelections();
             const rowDetails = this.getTable().getRow(rowUuids[0]);
                return rowDetails;
                 }
```

this row details contains the row which I have selected.
I need to display the details of the row in the side- pane which comes on the selection of the row.

this is my test view.js

```
        export default class TestView extends React.Component {
          private formRef: SFormComponent;
          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
            }
          }
          public render() {
           // console.log(ILandingPageProps)
            return (
              <div>
                <div>
                  <Collapse accordion>
                   <Panel header="Basic Information" key="2">
                     <SForm
                       {...this.getBasicInfoForm()}
                        wrappedComponentRef={form => (this.formRef = form)}
                      />
                    </Panel>
                  </Collapse>
               </div>
        <div>
          <Collapse accordion>
            <Panel header="Status Information" key="1">
              <SForm
                {...this.getStatusInfoForm()}
              />
            </Panel>
          </Collapse>,
      </div></div>
    );
           }
  private getBasicInfoForm() {
    const formConfig: ISFormProps = {
       initialData:this.props.imageSelectedRowUuid,
      sections: [
        {
          id: 'default',
          elements: [
            {
              type: SFormElementTypes.DESCRIPTION,
              id: 'image_name',
              name: 'image_name',
              label: 'Image Name',
              value: "check"
            },
            {
              type: SFormElementTypes.DESCRIPTION,
              id: 'os_version',
              name: 'os_version',
              label: 'OS Version',
              value: "check"
            },
            {
              type: SFormElementTypes.DESCRIPTION,
              id: 'vendor',
              name: 'vendor',
              label: 'Vendor',
              value: "check"
            },

            {
              type: SFormElementTypes.DESCRIPTION,
              id: 'family',
              name: 'family',
              label: "Family",
              value: "check"
            },

            {
              type: SFormElementTypes.DESCRIPTION,
              id: 'supported_platforms',
              name: 'supported_platforms',
              label: 'Supported Platforms',
              value: "check"
            },
          ]
        }]
    }
    return formConfig;
  }
  private getStatusInfoForm() {
    const formConfig: ISFormProps = {
      // initialData:this.props.imageSelectedRowUuid,
      sections: [
        {
          id: 'default',
          elements: [
            {
              type: SFormElementTypes.DESCRIPTION,
              id: 'configuration_status',
              name: 'configuration_status',
              label: 'Configuration Status',
              value: "check"
            },
          ]
        }]
    }
    return formConfig;
  }
}
```

I need to append the values in the value column of the table. Which is currently displayed as "check".
I am using react.js

Comment: try to use [React context](https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/context.html)  or somthing like [redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) to share state between component

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Redux-Store` to store your data globally and access the data as props to the component using `mapStateToProps`. By this way you can share data between components. On Clicking a table row, try to fetch the data with the key that you store with the rowData using a forLoop. Avoid using local state in your case. Hope It helps!!.